# Maikefile error make: *** [prepare] Error 127

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I get the following error form the Makefile:

```
VERSION=`git describe --abbrev=0 --tags`
TAG=$(VERSION)

all: prepare

prepare:
    $(TAG)
```

**Error:**

```
`git describe --abbrev=0 --tags`
/bin/sh: v1.1.2: command not found
make: *** [prepare] Error 127
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the `prepare` recipe trying to achieve?

Comment: `make: *** [TARGET] Error XXX` errors are always subcommand errors, FYI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your subshell command `git describe --abbrev=0 --tags` is executed an returns  the string "v1.1.2". Make then tries to execute it as a program.

```
prepare:
    echo $(TAG)
```

should work